# Undefine a defined header file / C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is it possible to undefine a header file which is already defined, from another header file?

I'm working with different classes and I need to undefine a certain class in order to change the private part to public.

I know it is not common to change a private to a public class but it could really help me out.

```
#undef "player.h"
#define private public
#include "player.h"
#undef private
```

Comment: *"I know is not common to change a private to a public class but it could really help me out."* Every time a developer thinks that, a kitten dies. Why don't you ask about the problem this "solves" instead?

Comment: This seams like a [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... what do you try to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: @Garf365 I'm working on a pokergame. There are multiple AI's in the game and I wondered if it could be possible to "hack" the chips. In other words just change the private variable which contains the amount of chips

Comment: Is it a "standard" functionality of your game ? In which context would you do that ? Because I think you have to think about your design than trying to "hack" your code

Comment: Header files are basically copy-pasted to the filw which #includes them. They are not "defined" in any sense of the word. Yoi could try temporaryily removing the #include and doing the copy-paste manually (open .h file, copy, switch to other file, remove the #include, paste the contents) to gain understanding of this.

Comment: I am only allowed to create AI's. Therefor I tought it would be nice to change the private variable and garantuee my win.

Comment: @ArmandLambrechts Just create a custom version of the .h file (just change private to public, nothing else, like re-ordering of member variables!) and include that instead of the original one. Tjat should work on any current compiler I think (it is probably Undefined Behavior in the standard, so I recommend compiling with optimizations off, and don't be surprised if it works unexpectedly anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, there are no preprocessor techniques that you can employ that remove statements from the code that's submitted to the compiler.

Secondly, C++ does not allow you to `#define` `private` as `public`. C++11 17.6.4.3.1 Macro names [macro.names]

> A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically
>   identical to keywords.

So **don't** do this.

The only thing you can really do in this situation is to retype the class.

Comment: Didn't know the holy standard took care of it. I feel genuine relief.

Comment: It actually does work. If I include this header first it works fine but the catch is when player.h is compiled first.

Comment: @ArmandLambrechts, your compiler is non-standard. On a newer one your code will break, and it's a good thing too.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ok I will look for another way. Thankyou

Comment: I reread [macro.names] and must admit I was wrong, therefore deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to redefine a class once it is defined. If you try, you will get an error message along these lines

> ```
>    error: redefinition of 'class player'
>      class player {
>            ^
> ```

Even redefining `private` into `public` before, e.g.

```
#define private public
#include "player.h"
#undef private
```

is dangerous and violates the contract for this class.

You should rather think about why this *seems* necessary, and refactor the class if possible.

Comment: "is dangerous", you're tellin' me it is. It's not allowed.

Comment: @Bathsheba This seems like an attempt to hack existing software, which is fine and worthy in and of itself. "Not allowed by standard" is irrelevant. Of course, doing this to cheat is rather unethical, I'm not implying cheating is ok.